# ComboBox template trigger IsMouseOver -> увеличить размер шрифта элемента в выпадающем списке

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Решил добавить красивости в combobox: в dropdown при наведении курсора увеличивать размер шрифта item'а. Не могу сообразить как достучаться до items.

Answer (score 3):

Скорее, вас интересует свойство `IsHighligghted`, а не `IsMouseOver`, потому что элементы можно выбирать и с клавиатуры. Непонятно, зачем вам "стучаться" к свойству `Items`. По сути, вам достаточно добавить триггер к стилю `ComboBoxItem`.

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Но должен предупредить, что изменение размера элемента при выделении — не лучшая идея. Кроме того, что это будет выглядеть непривычно, это может иметь непредвиденные последствия при отображении списка. Например, ширина выпадающего списка может прыгать.